# I have linux intalled when I boot it says no boot device found but in a live session all my data is there

Tags: ubuntu, boot

Here is the paste of boot-repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/12558734/

I can boot from a live usb and I can open the hdd and all of the data is there. 
My computer is a Dell M3800 with Ubuntu 14.04 installed. It came with Linux oem.

Answer (score 1):

None of the partitions on your first disk has the `bootable` flag set. Either set a partition as `bootable` using `gparted` from your live session, **or** tell your BIOS to boot from the other disk, which does have a partition marked `bootable`.